# Azure devops can't find custom nuget package

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, nuget, devops

I have a custom library that's packaged and published as a nuget package to this server:

https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-project-feed/_packaging/my-project-feed/nuget/v3/index.json

To my knowledge that's a public url (with restricted access [and a fake, in this case]).

I can add my library as a nuget package to my client application, everything builds and runs as expected so at least locally everything is fine.

However on the azure devops pipeline the build fails with this exception:

```
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1101: Unable to find package My.Custom.Package. No packages exist with this id in source(s): {C path}\dotnet\library-packs, NuGetOrg
Errors in {D path}\My.Blazor.Client\My.Blazor.Client.csproj
    NU1101: Unable to find package My.Custom.Package. No packages exist with this id in source(s): {C path}\dotnet\library-packs, NuGetOrg)
##[error]Packages failed to restore
```

If I add the package as a project reference by dll the build works fine.

My first suspicion is that this is a permissions issue. We are setting this environment up for first usage so it's likely we missed something.

**What I have tried**

There are two Project Build Service groups defined, I have tried giving both of them `Contributor` rights, one only had Collaborator, but that didn't change anything.

**My question**

- Is this indeed a permissions issue? If so, which service account (or group) would need what rights?
- If not, what could be happening?

Comment: Note your sources list. It doesn't include the project-feed. I am not a pipeline-guy (and thus cannot tell you how to add it, unfortunately). But my bet is on that pipeline-config issue.

Comment: @Fildor I am not sure I understand what you are looking at? To my knowledge `my-project` is the feed (not the real name of course). I've updated the link to better reflect the feed.

Comment: `No packages exist with this id in source(s): {C path}\dotnet\library-packs, NuGetOrg)` - It's querying the local folder "C:/dotnet/library-packs/" and NuGet.org for the package. But I guess that does not include the project feed "my-project" provided by your DevOps Artifacts. (i.e. https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-project-feed/_packaging/my-project-feed/nuget/v3/index.json) ?

Comment: Not sure, really but I think this could be related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#artifact-sources---azure-artifacts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `NuGet.config` file to your solution and add these lines:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value=".\packages" />
  </config>
  <packageSources>
     <add key="nuget.org" value ="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"/>
      <add key="AzureDevopsSource" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/my-project-feed/_packaging/my-project-feed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

then in your pipeline when doing the restore of the packages :

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore packages
  inputs:
    command: restore
    feedsToUse: config
    projects: '$(path-to-solution)'
    nugetConfigPath: 'NuGet.config'
    verbosityRestore: Normal
    includeNuGetOrg: true
```